# Изменить загружаемое фото Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Подскажите, загружаю фото на сервер через ajax, вот контроллер:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Intervention\Image\ImageManager;


class ClientDataController extends Controller {


    public function index() {
        
        return view('client-data');
    }

    public function upload_pass(Request $request)
    {
        foreach ($request->file() as $file) {
            $f = $file->move(storage_path('files'), time().'_'.$file->getClientOriginalName());
            $manager = new ImageManager(array('driver' => 'gd'));

            $image = $manager->make($f)->resize(100, 100);
            $put = storage_path('files');
            $file_name = time().'_'.$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $data = $put.$file_name;
            $image->save($data, 60);

            return $data;
        }
    }

}

?>
```

Нужно картинку которую передаю изменить resize() и вернуть путь измененной картинки на клиент, подозреваю что в моем коде не срабатывает save()/ Заранее спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно вернуть:

```
return $image->save($data, 60);
```